# Genymotion does not start (permission denied for androvm.gles.first)

Tags: android, opengl-es, virtualbox, genymotion

Genymotion is unable to start android virtual devices on my machine.

The Genymotion logs do not contain any relevant message. Instead, to debug the issue, I've launched the VM using vanilla virtualbox. The VM boots, and at some point starts to repeat the following message over and over again:

```
init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1000 name:androVM.gles.first_try
init: untracked pid <some number> exited
init: untracked pid <some other number> exited
```

The Genymotion FAQ suggests that the output of glewinfo could help with troubleshooting. [I've made it available here.](http://documents.epfl.ch/users/j/jo/jowagner/www/glewinfo.txt)

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the logs. I had problem with the network adapter and I figured it out from the logs.
I found my problem in the genymotion-player.log

More details about the GenyMotion logs
https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-logs

Comment: Thanks. But this does not look as if it were related to the network adapter. The logs do not contain information on this :( Booting in vanilla Virtualbox was the only thing that gave me at least some error message.

Comment: I said i had problem with the network adapter, i did not suggested that you have the same problem. Try to contact the genymotion support then maybe they can help you.

Comment: OK... I guess I was too harsh here. Sorry about that. I should have mentioned in the question that I already looked at the logs.

Comment: I've contacted Genymotion support about this, and they recommended me not to use the Gallium (nouveau) video driver, but the proprietary nvidia one. This solved the problem. So in the end... given that your answer is the only one and that your comment lead me to Genymotion support... I'll accept it as answer :)

Comment: It seems not many people knows about the Genymotion. You can pots an answer to your own question and accept it after a while. You should do that, because at the end you resolved your own problem and for people with same problem in the future can be more easily read if the correct solution is not in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I faced with to update the virtual device to the latest version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).