# Genymotion emulator won't start. Stays still forever in the "android" black bg screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin, genymotion

It's a fresh install, first time trying to use it, and it just doesn't work. This is all i get to see, with the CPU fan spinning fast all the time:

[image]

I wanted to see that little black monitor preview big to read the letters, it's all like this:

[image]

These are some of the errors I can see in the logs:

```
jul 21 09:46:53 [Genymotion] [Debug] Searching virtual device with same name 
jul 21 09:46:53 [Genymotion] [ERROR] VBoxManage ("showvminfo", "Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280") returns 1 
jul 21 09:46:53 [Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(VMNameOrUuid).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 2495 of file VBoxManageInfo.cpp" 
jul 21 09:46:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] Local OVA file computed SHA1 is  "218dfbd63bbe9d63bf866ca257211bc0ce3c6650" 
jul 21 09:46:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] Server said we should have that OVA hash:  "218dfbd63bbe9d63bf866ca257211bc0ce3c6650" 
jul 21 09:46:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] Searching virtual device with same name 
jul 21 09:46:56 [Genymotion] [ERROR] VBoxManage ("showvminfo", "Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280") returns 1 
jul 21 09:46:56 [Genymotion] [ERROR] Output command: "VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(VMNameOrUuid).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 2495 of file VBoxManageInfo.cpp"
```

Later on a **different try**:

```
jul 21 09:57:07 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "bridgedifs") returns 0 
jul 21 09:57:08 [Genymotion] [ERROR] VBoxManage ("list", "natnets") returns 2 
jul 21 09:57:08 [Genymotion] [ERROR] Output command: "Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.2.12
(C) 2005-2013 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage list [--long|-l] vms|runningvms|ostypes|hostdvds|hostfloppies|
                            bridgedifs|hostonlyifs|dhcpservers|hostinfo|
                            hostcpuids|hddbackends|hdds|dvds|floppies|
                            usbhost|usbfilters|systemproperties|extpacks|
                            groups


Syntax error: Unknown subcommand "natnets"." 
jul 21 09:57:08 [Genymotion] [ERROR] VBoxManage ("list", "intnets") returns 2 
jul 21 09:57:08 [Genymotion] [ERROR] Output command: "Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.2.12
(C) 2005-2013 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage list [--long|-l] vms|runningvms|ostypes|hostdvds|hostfloppies|
                            bridgedifs|hostonlyifs|dhcpservers|hostinfo|
                            hostcpuids|hddbackends|hdds|dvds|floppies|
                            usbhost|usbfilters|systemproperties|extpacks|
                            groups


Syntax error: Unknown subcommand "intnets"."
```

`VBoxSVC.log` is filled with these:

```
00:15:28.362000          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 1 on port 1 of controller 'IDEController'}, preserve=false
00:15:28.362000          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 1 on port 1 of controller 'IDEController'}, preserve=false
00:15:29.080000          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 1 on port 1 of controller 'IDEController'}, preserve=false
00:15:29.080000          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 1 on port 1 of controller 'IDEController'}, preserve=false
```

In `Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280-genymotion-player.log` I have some of these as well:

```
jul 21 09:50:34 [Genymotion Player] [ERROR] Unable to connect to  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.102" )  : 22666 "Socket operation timed out" 
jul 21 09:50:34 [Genymotion Player] [ERROR] Fail to send capabilities request 
jul 21 09:50:34 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Timeout waiting for capabilities. Will retry. 
jul 21 09:50:37 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Events Manager: requesting device capabilities 
jul 21 09:50:39 [Genymotion Player] [ERROR] Unable to connect to  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.102" )  : 22666 "Socket operation timed out" 
jul 21 09:50:39 [Genymotion Player] [ERROR] Fail to send capabilities request 
jul 21 09:50:39 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Timeout waiting for capabilities. Will retry. 
jul 21 09:50:42 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Events Manager: requesting device capabilities 
jul 21 09:50:44 [Genymotion Player] [ERROR] Unable to connect to  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.102" )  : 22666 "Socket operation timed out" 
jul 21 09:50:44 [Genymotion Player] [ERROR] Fail to send capabilities request 
jul 21 09:50:44 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Timeout waiting for capabilities. Will retry. 
jul 21 09:50:47 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Events Manager: requesting device capabilities 
jul 21 09:50:49 [Genymotion Player] [ERROR] Unable to connect to  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.102" )  : 22666 "Socket operation timed out" 
jul 21 09:50:49 [Genymotion Player] [ERROR] Fail to send capabilities request 
jul 21 09:50:49 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Timeout waiting for capabilities. Will retry.
```

I've [**uploaded here at pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/JfzEtE5P) the results of searching the word "error" in all log files generated by genymotion (456 hits in 16 files).

Everybody on the internet praises this emulator so much that i don't want to give up so fast, but I certainly don't know how to fix it. I've googled these different errors, nothing of use.

Comment: In your first screenshot, I see that you have VirtualBox open. Are you starting the Nexus VM from the Genymotion launcher or VirtualBox? You should try starting it from the Genymotion launcher without having VB open at all. Genymotion VMs do not usually startup when launched directly from VirtualBox.

Comment: Yes, i launch it from Genymotion. I just opened VB to try to get more insight to the problem. The thing I then tried a different model and it worked... Not my model though.

Comment: ADB the mystery continues.

Comment: Do you try other image? Do you have other virtualization software like VMWare or Hyper-V? Other way I do is in vbox settings set the Android machine network to bridge, for the log I think you have in nat.

Comment: What worked for me are following 3 steps. 1. Uninstall GM (incl. VirtualBox).& restart 2. Install GM (incl. VirtualBox and not separately) & restart, 3. Set GM to use its own ADB (Settings -> ADB -> Use Genymotion Android Tools).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I tried many things for days then I noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449775/genymotion-does-not-start-permission-denied-for-androvm-gles-first#19449924). It was mentioned that they had a network problem and I remembered in my general-genymotion.log file I saw this line:

`[Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "VBoxManage: error: DHCP server does not exist"`
My problem was solved after I removed DHCP's from my network also I cleared all catches from genymotion

Also used my local ADB instead of genymotion's default:

`Genymotion->Settings->ADB->Use custome Android SDK tools`

After that:

`Genymotion->Settings->Misc->Clear cache`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by setting a static ip address in the same field of addresses as where my network card ipv4 is (in my case 192.168.1.75 so it's between  192.168.1.2 and  192.168.1.255) to the virtual box network adapter [like in these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486549/1705922) so it won't need DHCP anymore.